# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create map: Failed to read configuration file:

Tags: here-api

I am implementing HERE maps for Android applicaiton, I keep getting a crash in the HERE map SDK with the following error

```
 Process: my.app.package, PID: 30682
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create map: Failed to read configuration file: /data/user/0/my.app.package/files/.here-maps/someid/mwconfig_client
    at com.nokia.maps.MapImpl.<init>(MapImpl.java:451)
    at com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map.<init>(Map.java:710)
    at com.nokia.maps.bw.m(MapFragmentImpl.java:546)
    at com.nokia.maps.bw.a(MapFragmentImpl.java:583)
    at com.nokia.maps.bw.a(MapFragmentImpl.java:85)
    at com.nokia.maps.bw$1.onEngineInitializationCompleted(MapFragmentImpl.java:135)
    at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine$10.run(MapsEngine.java:2471)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Its not reproducible always but its happens 50% of the time.

I can see this issue still open in HERE maps site, https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/issues/134

I seek help from the HERE maps team, and any solution to this problem will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probbaly the case that there is another app on your device using the SDK and the MapServices from the two apps are conflicting with each other. You could try setting the isolated disck cache for your app as desribed in the documentation (https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-service.html) helps

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
  android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"
  android:label="{YOUR_LABEL_NAME}"
  android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="{YOUR_INTENT_NAME}">
    </action>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

MapActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  // Search for the map fragment to finish setup by calling init().
  mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
  boolean success = com.here.android.mpa.common.MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(
    getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + ".here-maps",
    "{YOUR_INTENT_NAME}");

  if (!success) {
    // Setting the isolated disk cache was not successful, please check if the path is valid and
    // ensure that it does not match the default location
    // (getExternalStorageDirectory()/.here-maps).
    // Also, ensure the provided intent name does not match the default intent name.
  } else {
    mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually these lines were missing in my code, boolean success = com.here.android.mpa.common.MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(
    getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + ".here-maps",
    "{YOUR_INTENT_NAME}");

  if (!success) {

Comment: @jithin I am facing the same issue with some of my users and I am using the separate map service and isolated disk cache. any idea what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error is happening just in android 11 version. After some research I have found that changing Files Directory from **getExternalFilesDir** to **getFilesDir** works fine for me. In that case the success variable should be:

boolean success = com.here.android.mpa.common.MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(
m_fragment.getContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + File.separator + ".here-maps",
"MAP_INTENT KEY that Should match with key in manifest file");

Comment: Like you, in my case this error is happening just in android 11 version. Before, I was doing that : Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + File.separator + "myfile". Now, I do that: filesDir.absolutePath + File.separator + "myfile"